# on a moving element don't fire the mouse events

Tags: jquery, html, tooltip, mouseleave

a tooltip will show when mouse over a moving div, but ,the div is moving,it doesn't fire the mouse events,see the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/jcezG/6/  (firefox 23.0.1 is ok).
`

```
$('.area').on('mouseenter',function(){
    $('.tooltip').show();
}).on('mouseleave',function(){
    $('.tooltip').hide();
});
var offset = 10;
setInterval(function(){
    //$('.area').hide();
    $('.area').css({"-webkit-transform":"translate("+offset+"px,"+offset+"px)"});
    //$('.area').css({"left":offset+'px',"top":offset+'px'});
    offset += 10;
},1000);
```

`

forgive my poor english.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.area').on('mouseenter',function(){
    $('.tooltip').show();
}).on('mousemove', function(e){
   $('.tooltip').css({'top':e.pageY,'left':e.pageX, 'z-index':'1'});
}).on('mouseleave',function(){
    $('.tooltip').hide();
});

var offset = 10;
setInterval(function(){
    //$('.area').hide();
    $('.area').css({"-webkit-transform":"translate("+offset+"px,"+offset+"px)","-moz-transform":"translate("+offset+"px,"+offset+"px)"});
    //$('.area').css({"left":offset+'px',"top":offset+'px'});
    offset += 10;
},1000);
```

Check this line "$('.area').css({"-webkit-transform":"translate("+offset+"px,"+offset+"px)","-moz-transform":"translate("+offset+"px,"+offset+"px)"});
        //$('.area').css({"left":offset+'px',"top":offset+'px'});" Is that the way you want ? check the fiddle [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Aveendra/jcezG/21/)

Comment: You have to use word "-moz-" if you are using css3 for moz browsers. Firefox is -moz- browser. That was why it didnt work for firefox. if you are using css3 IE you have use word "-ms-" .

Comment: oh,sorry. i mean, when your mouse on the .area and don't move the mouse(your hand can be left), then the .area will still move until the static mouse out of it, but at this time , the mouseleave event not trigger,the tooltip is still displayed,I would like to make the tooltip disappear at this time

Comment: oops,but when the mouse follow the .area, the tooltip will disappear after 5s

Comment: I guess this is a bug, but only Firefox implement it

Answer (score 0):

can you please replace your code with this

and set left and top postion at time of mouseover

```
$('.area').on('mouseenter',function(){
     $('.tooltip').show();
}).on('mousemove', function(e){
     $('.tooltip').css({'top':e.pageY,'left':e.pageX});
}).on('mouseleave',function(){
     $('.tooltip').hide();
});
```

and set z-index:100; in tooltip class

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/malvaniya_shakti/jcezG/20/)

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the div position as well as mouse pointer position and fire same effect on mouseenter and mousemove to get the latest position of mouse pointer.

```
var x,y;

$('.area').on('mouseenter mousemove',function(e){
    //console.log(e.pageX + "|" + e.pageY);
    x= e.pageX;
    y=e.pageY;
    $('.tooltip').css({'top':e.pageY,'left':e.pageX + 15, 'z-index':'1'}).show();
}).on('mouseleave',function(){
    $('.tooltip').hide();
});
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jcezG/27/) for more detail

Comment: yes, thx,but I still think this is a browser bug. the browser should deal it, not me

Comment: whats the problem now.

Comment: actually, the div moving is random